# Not able to unit test API controller using moq. Where I'm going wrong?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, moq

Controller class

```
[Route("hollywood/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        List<Film> film = new List<Film>()
        {
            new Film(){id=1,name="The Dark Knight",director="Christopher Nolan", release=2008},
            new Film(){id=2,name="300",director="Zack Snyder", release=2007},
            new Film(){id=3,name="Titanic",director="James Cameron", release=1997},
        };

        // GET film/movies
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            // some code
            return Json(film);
        }

        // GET film/movies/{id}
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            // some code
            return Json(film.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Film value)
        {
            // some code
            film.Add(value);
            return Json(film);
        }
    }
```

Model Class

```
public class Film
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string director { get; set; }
        public int release { get; set; }
    }
```

Test

```
[Fact]
        public async Task TestGet()
        {
            List<Film> film = new List<Film>()
            {
                new Film(){id=1,name="The Dark Knight",director="Christopher Nolan", release=2008},
                new Film(){id=2,name="300",director="Zack Snyder", release=2007},
                new Film(){id=3,name="Titanic",director="James Cameron", release=1997},
            };

            // Arrange
            string expectedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(film);
            var requestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:51867/film/movies");

            // Act
            var mockHandler = new Mock<MoviesController>();

            mockHandler
                .Setup(x => x.Get())
                .Returns(expectedResult);

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object);  
            var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(expectedResult, result);
        }
```

I'm performing unit testing using moq. I need to mock the Get/Post calls in Controllers using Moq HttpClient. I'm unable to mock the object. Please let me know what am I doing wrong? Is IActionResult return type causing it to fail? If yes, what else can I use instead of IActionResult?

Comment: No need to mock controller under test. Second if unit testing then HttpClient is not needed. Create an instance of the controller,invoke the member under test, and assert expected behavior against actual behavior. Nothing you have shown so far required mocking anything.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Reference [Test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I don't understand why cannot I mock it? I want to check if the response I'm getting for calling the get request is the same as what I expect.

Comment: You are using httpclient to call a URL to an endpoint that does not exist at the time of testing.You do not need that HttpClient for unit test. Based on what you have shown you do not even need Moq.